# csshX not working after updating macOS to Ventura 13.2.1

Tags: ventura, perl

I installed `csshX` with `brew` and it was working well until I upgraded to Ventura 13.2.1 (22D68). I have the issue below:

```
Unimplemented: POSIX::tmpnam(): use File::Temp instead at /System/Library/Perl/5.34/darwin-thread-multi-2level/POSIX.pm line 185.
Unimplemented: POSIX::tmpnam() at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1130.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1130.
```

So I modified the `csshX` file to look like:

```
use base       qw(CsshX::Socket::Selectable);
#use POSIX     qw(tmpnam);
use File::Temp qw/:POSIX/;
use FindBin    qw($Bin $Script);
```

However I am getting this error:

```
Can't locate Foundation.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Foundation module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.34/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.34 /Network/Library/Perl/5.34/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.34 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.34.0 /System/Library/Perl/5.34/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.34 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.34) at (eval 8) line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 8) line 1.
```

I see this in `csshX`:

```
my $terminal;
sub init {
    eval "use Foundation; use List::Util qw(min max)";
    die $@ if $@;
}
```

How can I install this `Foundation` module?

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this same problem on Ventura 13.2.1 as well. I modified the `/usr/local/bin/csshx` file to look like:

(line 1)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl5.30
```

(line 1130)

```
#use POSIX     qw(tmpnam);
use File::Temp   qw(tmpnam);
```

That fixed it for me!

Comment: Thanks this resolved the issue for me too!